# How can I remove the white space in the beginning of a text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I notice when I put a text there is a white space at the beginning and is not aligned with the other divs:

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <h1 class="display-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Más información</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't remove it, I tried with `white-space: unset` but it doesn't work. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

I'd like your help.

Comment: I don't think you want to remove that, It's reserved for letters like `Z,W,A,X`, Also it depends on the font.

Comment: This is what it might do to other Characters if we follow the letter with the most space before it `L` in `monospace`  https://jsfiddle.net/580ra2Lg/